# Can I use just 2 sets of background pictures for my app and still support iphone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have 2 files called image.png and image@2x.png sizes: 320x568 and 640x1136.
If I use those files as background, does this solve the dead space on the iphone 5? Will the iphone 5 load the @2x picture? I understand that in an iphone with 3.5 and lower the background picture will get cut but I don't really care about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project that is for both iPhone 5 and the four.  For my background image, I made a uiview that was the size of the entire view.  I then hooked this up to my background jpeg file.  Under mode in the attributes inspector,  I selected scale to fill.  Since the uiview is held to all sides of the view, it works for both.  It looks great in either size screen.  The jpeg is pretty high res, but I didnt need to place any @2x.  Hope this helps you out.